# After generate-xcodeproj, what steps enable statical linking of the SPM-generated Xcode project as subproject in another Xcode project?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

**Motivation:** It would be useful to be able to generate a SPM-based static library Xcode project that can be [referenced from another (not SPM-base) Xcode project](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/9.0/#/dev7b72b5ea5). `generate-xcodeproj` seemed like a reasonable approach to try, however, `generate-xcodeproj` creates is a dynamic framework project instead of a static library project.

**Question:** After `generate-xcodeproj`, what Xcode steps (for Xcode 9 and Swift 4) are needed to static link a `type: .static` Swift Package Library into a simple command line binary executable … similar to what is produced by corresponding `swift build`?

In other words, how end up with a SPM-generated static library Xcode project that can be used as a subproject in a non-SPM Xcode project.

**Goal:** Produce a statically linked executable with Xcode like what is produced by `swift build` from the command line *… for the same module product.*

The issue is that the `generate-xcodeproj` produced project creates a dynamically linked product (not expected) while `swift build` produces a statically linked product (as expected).

**Example:** Consider two Swift Manager Packages (SPM) packages:

1. static library: [`TinkerEvalStaticLib`⇗](https://github.com/VaporExamplesLab/TinkerEvalStaticLib) with `swift package init --type library` as the starting point.
2. command line executable: [`TinkerEvalStaticCli`⇗](https://github.com/VaporExamplesLab/TinkerEvalStaticCli) with `swift package init --type executable` as the starting point.

`TinkerEvalStaticLib` is simple and expressly set to a type `.static`.

*TinkerEvalStaticLib.swift*

```swift
public class TinkerEvalStaticLib {
    public static func printSomething() -> String {
        let s = "Library says, 'Hello.'"
        print(s)
        return s
    }
}
```

*Package.swift*

```swift
…
products: [
    .library(name: "TinkerEvalStaticLib", 
    type: .static, // expressly set to be a static library
    …
```

`TinkerEvalStaticCli` is also simple and has `TinkerEvalStaticLib` as a dependency.

*main.swift*

```swift
import TinkerEvalStaticLib
let _ = TinkerEvalStaticLib.printSomething()
```

*Package.swift*

```swift
…
name: "TinkerEvalStaticCli",
dependencies: [
  .package(
    url: "git@github.com:VaporExamplesLab/TinkerEvalStaticLib.git",
    .branch("master") ),
],
…
```

**Observation:**

1. In the `TinkerEvalStaticCli` directory, `swift build` will create a standalone relocatable, statically linked executable.

```
prompt> ./TinkerEvalStaticCli_spm 
Library says, 'Hello.'
```

2. However, the Xcode project created with `swift package generate-xcodeproj` creates a dynamically linked executable that requires the separate library.

```
prompt> ./TinkerEvalStaticCli_xc 
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/TinkerEvalStaticLib.framework/Versions/A/TinkerEvalStaticLib
  Referenced from: /Users/…/./TinkerEvalStaticCli_xc
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

**Note:** One would expect that an `swift package generate-xcodeproj` generated Xcode project would build a static linked binary (instead of a dynamic linked binary) similar to the static linked binary produced by the corresponding `swift build`. So, this question is for a workaround to a current SPM `generate-xcodeproj` limitation.

Comment: Honestly, this is way too deep for me to answer. But *why* are you saying "one would expect" two different commands to end up with the same result? By looks, I'd expect `generate-xcodeproj` to result in a *single* Xcode project (and possible executable) while `swift build` would result in *building* (or compiling) Swift code.

Comment: @dfd Too clarify … Since the dependent library is expressly `type: .static` in the library's `Package.swift`, then either approach should _ultimately create_ a statically linked binary.  (Approach 1) `swift build` directly creates a binary based on `Package.swift`. (Approach 2) `swift package generate-xcodeproj` creates an Xcode project based on the _same `Package.swift`_ which in turn creates a binary product. _… which is expected to be likewise statically linked due to use of the same `Package.swift` files_.

Comment: Reported issue as [SR-6805 generate-xcodeproj does not honor library type: .static](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6805) for Swift Package Manager component.

Answer (score 0):

The Swift package model is not a one-to-one mapping to Xcode's model so there are some differences. The `generate-xcodeproj` command is intended for developers who prefer to work in Xcode IDE. That said, we do need to move the generated Xcode project from frameworks to static libraries so there are more similarities.

I suggest using `swift build` to create the actual statically linked binaries.

Comment: Ideally, one would be able generate a SPM-base Xcode static library project which could be [referenced from another (not SPM-base) Xcode project](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/9.0/#/dev7b72b5ea5). It seemed reasonable to expect `generate-xcodeproj` to generate such a project since Xcode already has a build-in static Library project template. Any know path(s) to generate a SPM-base static library Xcode project?